# SQL - Combining Dynamic SQL with Pivot and Full Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql

I am looking for a solution/suggestion. I've searched not only Stackoverflow but Googled for days and still haven't found a suitable solution.

Scenario:

- I have 2 database tables - A and B.
- I need to do a select query against both A and B based on same parameter.
- The resultset from both A and B will need to be pivoted separately.
- After pivoting, a full join needs to be performed.

---

```
declare     @Tickers nvarchar(MAX),
@StartDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime,
@Field nvarchar(10);

select @Tickers ='[ADDRC BDSR Curncy], [USDRC BDSR Curncy], [JYDRC BDSR Curncy], [NDDRC BDSR Curncy], [BPDRC BDSR Curncy], [SFDRC BDSR Curncy], [CDDRC BDSR Curncy], [NKDRC BDSR Curncy], [DKDRC BDSR Curncy], [SKDRC BDSR Curncy], [EUDRC BDSR Curncy], [KWDRC BDSR Curncy], [IRDRC BDSR Curncy], [CGDRC BDSR Curncy], [HFDRC BDSR Curncy], [CKDRC BDSR Curncy], [SADRC BDSR Curncy], [PZDRC BDSR Curncy], [MPDRC BDSR Curncy]',
@StartDate = '01/05/1990' ,
@EndDate = '01/13/2016',
@Field = 'PX_LAST';

DECLARE @pTickers nvarchar(MAX) = @Tickers,
    @pStartDate datetime = @StartDate,
    @pEndDate datetime = @EndDate,
    @pField nvarchar(10) = @Field,
    @pSQL nvarchar(MAX);

--Dynamic SQL
SET @pSQL = '
;With CTE as
(
  SELECT * FROM
  (
      SELECT SecurityIdentifier as [Ticker], PriceDate as [pDate], Price as [Price] FROM Bbg_' + @pField  +
' WHERE PriceDate BETWEEN ''' + CAST(@pStartDate as nvarchar) + ''' AND ''' + cast(@pEndDate as NVARCHAR) +'''
  ) as s
PIVOT
(
  MIN (s.Price)
  for [Ticker] in (' + @pTickers + ') -- Column names for pivot
) as pvt
)
Select * from CTE a
order by a.pDate DESC'
EXECUTE(@pSQL);
```

This code will generate a pivoted resultset against one of the tables. I will need to do the same thing with the second table and then full join the two results based on priceDate/pDate.

Am I doing this the right way?

**Edit:**

```
Table Bbg_PX_LAST
==========================================
| SecurityIdentifier  | PriceDate | Price|
------------------------------------------
| ADDRC BDSR Curncy   | 03/02/2016| 10.00|
| ADDRC BDSR Curncy   | 04/02/2016| 11.00|
| ADDRC BDSR Curncy   | 05/02/2016| 12.00|
| ADDRC BDSR Curncy   | 06/02/2016| 13.00|
| USDRC BDSR Curncy   | 03/02/2016| 20.00|
| USDRC BDSR Curncy   | 04/02/2016| 21.00|
| USDRC BDSR Curncy   | 05/02/2016| 22.00|
| USDRC BDSR Curncy   | 06/02/2016| 23.00|
==========================================

Table Bbg_CUR_PX
==========================================
| SecurityIdentifier  | PriceDate | Price|
------------------------------------------
| ADDRC BDSR Curncy   | 03/02/2016| 30.00|
| ADDRC BDSR Curncy   | 04/02/2016| 31.00|
| ADDRC BDSR Curncy   | 05/02/2016| 32.00|
| ADDRC BDSR Curncy   | 06/02/2016| 33.00|
| USDRC BDSR Curncy   | 03/02/2016| 40.00|
| USDRC BDSR Curncy   | 04/02/2016| 41.00|
| USDRC BDSR Curncy   | 05/02/2016| 42.00|
==========================================

Result:

================================================================================
| PDate       | ADDRC BDSR | ADDRC BDSR  | USDRC BDSR | USDRC BDSR  | .....
|             | Curncy     | Curncy (2)  | Curncy     | Curncy (2)  |  ....
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 03/02/2016  |  10.00     |   30.00     |  20.00     |   40.00     |   ...
| 04/02/2016  |  11.00     |   31.00     |  21.00     |   41.00     |   ...
| 05/02/2016  |  12.00     |   32.00     |  22.00     |   42.00     |   ...
| 06/02/2015  |  13.00     |   33.00     |  23.00     |   NULL      |   ...
================================================================================

*ADDRC BDSR Curncy      - is from table Bbg_PX_LAST
*ADDRC BDSR Curncy (2)  - is from table Bbg_CUR_PX
*USDRC BDSR Curncy      - is from table Bbg_PX_LAST
*USDRC BDSR Curncy (2)  - is from table Bbg_CUR_PX
```

There are more columns in the final result. This sample is provided with only two (2) to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you add some sample data and an expected output?  SO has a [great guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to composing this stuff, if you need a little inspiration.

Comment: Do you have a specific question other than "Am I doing this the right way?". This will lead to opinion based answers.

Comment: I feel like if you described the original problem (along with sample data, etc.) you were trying to solve, we can probably solve this in a better way.  Your approach may work (it may even be the best one), but without having that context, I can't tell you if there is a better way.

Comment: @ChrisPickford: That might be true - but I am having trouble joining the two tables together because of the pivots which uses a string parameter with dynamic values. My SQL is very rusty.

Comment: @Becuzz: I have an Excel with 2 columns. One contains IDs and the other fields. This Excel will make a call to SQL stored proc via macros. for each ID's I need to extract the value of the x number of fields. For example, if we have ID (A,B,C) and fields (1,2,3) - my resultset should be A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1,C2,C3 - in the above tabular format. The result will be fed back into Excel. I thought by doing the join at SQL level, it would make it easier than running a loop in a macro which could potentially run for a long time (cell per cell). Not  sure if this helps. But thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do:

- Rewrite `@pSQL` to not use a WITH clause (it is superfluous)
- Generate the PIVOT SQL for table A and B separately, as you have already done for one table: `@pSQLA` and `@pSQLB`
- Write a query that combines both, having a FULL JOIN between a derived table for `A` and `B`

---

Simplified example:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cmd=N'
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        ('+@pSQLA+') AS A
        FULL JOIN ('+@pSQLB+') AS B ON
            A.PDate=B.PDate;
';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @cmd;
```

Comment: That is perfect. Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Selects NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Identifiers NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SUM(CASE WHEN l.SecurityIdentifier = ''<ticker>>'' THEN l.Price END) AS ''<ticker>>'',
                                  SUM(CASE WHEN c.SecurityIdentifier = ''<ticker>>'' THEN c.Price END) AS ''<ticker>> (2)'''

SELECT  @Selects = COALESCE(@Selects + ',', '') + REPLACE(@Identifiers, '<ticker>>', SecurityIdentifier)
FROM    Bbg_PX_LAST
GROUP BY SecurityIdentifier

SET @Sql = '
SELECT
    COALESCE(l.PriceDate, c.PriceDate) PDate, '
    + @Selects + 
'FROM 
    Bbg_PX_LAST l
    FULL OUTER JOIN Bbg_CUR_PX c ON l.SecurityIdentifier = c.SecurityIdentifier AND l.PriceDate = c.PriceDate
GROUP BY 
    COALESCE(l.PriceDate, c.PriceDate)'

EXEC(@Sql)
```

This will dynamically build a sql based on the `SecurityIdentifier` column of one of the tables, in this case table `Bbg_PX_LAST`.  The resulting query would look like this.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(l.PriceDate,c.PriceDate) PDate,
        SUM(CASE WHEN l.SecurityIdentifier = 'ADDRC BDSR Curncy' THEN l.Price END) AS 'ADDRC BDSR Curncy',
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.SecurityIdentifier = 'ADDRC BDSR Curncy' THEN c.Price END) AS 'ADDRC BDSR Curncy (2)',
        SUM(CASE WHEN l.SecurityIdentifier = 'USDRC BDSR Curncy' THEN l.Price END) AS 'USDRC BDSR Curncy',
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.SecurityIdentifier = 'USDRC BDSR Curncy' THEN c.Price END) AS 'USDRC BDSR Curncy (2)'
FROM    Bbg_PX_LAST l
        FULL OUTER JOIN Bbg_CUR_PX c ON l.SecurityIdentifier = c.SecurityIdentifier
                                        AND l.PriceDate = c.PriceDate
GROUP BY COALESCE(l.PriceDate,c.PriceDate)
```

Comment: The query took at least 5 mins to run. Its probably because there is a large recordset stored. But thanks for your suggestion.